# Gridview Delete Link returns "[ERROR] : Deleting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless DeleteCommand is specified."

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a reservation system and I am having a problem with my delete link that is inside my gridview that is supposedly to delete temporarily reserved rooms, it returns an error page stating that "Deleting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless DeleteCommand is specified." but when I relog-in the account I used the data was removed. Here is my code

ASP.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="cartGView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ROOM_ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" Width="100%" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="Horizontal" OnRowDeleting="cartGView_RowDeleting">
                        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign ="Center" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField SelectText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ROOM_ID" HeaderText="Room ID" SortExpression="ROOM_ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ROOM_TYPE" HeaderText="Room Type" SortExpression="ROOM_TYPE" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="NO_GUEST" HeaderText="Guest" SortExpression="NO_GUEST" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PRICE" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="PRICE" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SUB_PRICE" HeaderText="Sub Price" SortExpression="SUB_PRICE" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                        </Columns>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <br></br><center>Select Room</center>
                            <br></br>
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Bakasyunan %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ROOM_ID], [ROOM_TYPE], [PRICE], [SUB_PRICE], [NO_GUEST] FROM [TBL_MyCart] WHERE ([USERNAME] = @USERNAME)" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:SessionParameter Name="USERNAME" SessionField="username" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C#:

```
protected void cartGView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string roomid = Convert.ToString(cartGView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
            cd.DeleteRecordWalkCart(roomid);
            cartGView.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
            cartGView.DataBind();


            if (cartGView.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                subtotalBox.Text = "P 0.00";
                continueBtn.Enabled = false;
                continueBtn.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2C2A2A");
            }
            else if (cartGView.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                SqlCommand sumcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(SUB_PRICE) FROM TBL_MyCart", conn); //<-- Add Subtotal
                conn.Open();
                string sum = sumcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                conn.Close();
                subtotalBox.Text = "P " + sum + ".00";
                continueBtn.Enabled = true;
                continueBtn.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#6c0404");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless DeleteCommand is specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948897/deleting-is-not-supported-by-data-source-sqldatasource1-unless-deletecommand-i)

Comment: I don't get it, can you please explain it to me if convenient?